# How to replace two char with another char in a char array using C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The question is; I need to replace "AB" with "C" in a string.

Example 1:

> "HEABLO" to "HECLO"

Code:

```
    int main() {
    int i=0,j=0;
    char a[]="helablo";
    while(i<strlen(a)-1){
        if(a[i]=='a'&& a[i+1]=='b'){
            a[j]='\0';
            a[j++]='c';
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(i==strlen(a)){
        printf("%s\n",a);
    }
    a[j]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

There is no error and there is no output.

Comment: You can't replace two array elements with one. What will happen to the extra space?

Comment: `a[j]='\0';` Why do this.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code. You will learn a lot!

Comment: Don'twrite`while(i<strlen(a)-1)`do`for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0'&&a[i+1]!='\0';++i)`instead. And use more white space because your code is as my previous statement VERY UNPLEASANT TO READ.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/XFo0ro)

Comment: "there is no output." because `i==strlen(a)` is not true.  `i==strlen(a)` is not true due to `a[j]='\0';` shorten the string after `i` was computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way to achieve what you want. Happens in a single pass.

```
char* o=input;
char* i=input;
for(;*o=*i;i++,o++)
    *o=(i[0]=='a' && i[1]=='b' && i++)? 'c': *i;
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://ideone.com/n66nVF)

The `for` loop simply copies a letter from input to output position 1 character at a time. This loop will go on untill `*i` is not 0 (`'\0'`).

So no changes will happen basically. But the line inside checks if input has a and b consequtively just where it is writting. If it is so the third part of the condition gets evaluated causing it to skip one character from input.

And when it evaluates to true, output gets written with `'c'`. Else it overwrites the old value.

The same code in a simple way would be as follows.

```
for (; *input != '\0'; i++) {
    if( input[0] == 'a' && input[1] == 'b'){
        input++;
        *output = 'c';
    } else {
        *output = *input;
    }
    output++;
}
```

I hope this one helps understanding better. The one mentioned above is just a compact (maybe complex) way to write the same logic.

Comment: could you please explain for(;*o=*i;i++,o++)
        *o=(i[0]=='a' && i[1]=='b' && i++)? 'c': *i;

Comment: @Aravind I have added explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a more general function to replace a substring with a single character, using `strstr()` to find the substring, and `memmove()` to rewrite the end of the string.

The `strstr()` function finds the first occurrence of a substring within an input string, or returns a null pointer if no match is found. This pointer can be used to assign the desired `char` to the input string. Then `memmove()` can be used to move the characters from the end of the string to the location following the substituted character. If `loc` is a pointer to the location of the found substring, and `replace_len` is the length of the substring to be replaced, then `char *tail = loc + replace_len` points to the tail of the input string that should be kept, and `strlen(tail) + 1` is the number of characters to move, including the `'\0'` character.

This function only replaces the first occurrence of a substring; if it is desired to replace *all* occurrences of a substring, this function can be called in a loop. Since `substr_char()` returns a pointer to the character following the substituted character (or a null pointer when no substitution is made), the return value can be used in a loop to continue making substitutions until no more matches are found.

The method described above is not as efficient as it might be for replacing all occurrences of a substring, since the entire tail of the string is moved, including remaining instances of the substring to be replaced, each time `substr_char()` is called. This method can be modified so that no extra characters are copied by writing a single function to replace all instances of the replacement substring. This function, `substr_char_all()`, finds the first instance of the substring, and writes the replacement character to the location indicated by `next`, and then finds the next instance of the substring in `tail`. If there is no such instance, `tail` is moved to follow the replacement character. If there is another instance of the substring, the characters preceding this instance are moved to follow the replacement character. The number of characters to move is found by subtracting `tail` from `loc`, since `tail` points to the start of the remainder of the string, and `loc` points to the start of the next substring instance. Note that both `tail` and `loc` are pointers, so the correct type to store this result is `ptrdiff_t`. The pointer `next` is then incremented to indicate the location following the moved characters, and the loop continues, writing a replacement character to the next location, and searching for more instances of the replacement substring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>           // for ptrdiff_t, used in substr_char_all()

char * substr_char(char *str, char *substr, char c);
void substr_char_all(char *st, char *subst, char c);

int main(void)
{
    /* Replace the first occurrence of a substring with a character */
    char string1[] = "heablo";
    printf("Before substitution: %s\n", string1);
    char *found = substr_char(string1, "ab", 'l');
    printf("After substitution: %s\n", string1);

    putchar('\n');

    /* Replace all occurrences of a substring with a character */
    char string2[] = "heababababloo";
    printf("Before substitution: %s\n", string2);
    found = string2;
    while ((found = substr_char(found, "ab", 'l'))) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("After substitution: %s\n", string2);

    /* Using the substr_char_all() function */
    putchar('\n');
    char string3[] = "heablo";
    printf("Before substitution: %s\n", string3);
    substr_char_all(string3, "ab", 'l');
    printf("After substitution: %s\n", string3);

    putchar('\n');
    char string4[] = "heababababloo";
    printf("Before substitution: %s\n", string4);
    substr_char_all(string4, "ab", 'l');
    printf("After substitution: %s\n", string4);

    putchar('\n');
    char string5[] = "some body wants some thing";
    printf("Before substitution: %s\n", string5);
    substr_char_all(string5, "some", 'a');
    printf("After substitution: %s\n", string5);

    return 0;
}

/* Returns a pointer to the character following substitution, or NULL */
char * substr_char(char *st, char *subst, char c)
{
    char *loc = strstr(st, subst);
    if (loc) {
        *loc = c;
        char *tail = loc + strlen(subst);
        memmove(loc + 1, tail, strlen(tail) + 1);
        ++loc;
    }

    return loc;
}

void substr_char_all(char *st, char *subst, char c)
{
    char *loc = strstr(st, subst);
    char *next = loc;
    while (loc) {
        *next++ = c;
        char *tail = loc + strlen(subst);
        if ((loc = strstr(tail, subst))) {
            ptrdiff_t copy_len = loc - tail;
            memmove(next, tail, copy_len);
            next += copy_len;
        } else {
            memmove(next, tail, strlen(tail) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Before substitution: heablo
After substitution: hello

Before substitution: heababababloo
After substitution: hellllloo

Before substitution: heablo
After substitution: hello

Before substitution: heababababloo
After substitution: hellllloo

Before substitution: some body wants some thing
After substitution: a body wants a thing
```

Comment: If I get it right won't this have a complexity of O(n^2)? It can be done in a single pass though.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya-- I wasn't too concerned with efficiencies here, but I have added a function to my answer that uses `strstr()` and `memmove()` while avoiding the extra copying.

Answer (score 0):

There is no output because you explicitly have coded it to only output something in one specific circumstance...which will never happen. The expression in this `if` statement will always be false

```
if(i==strlen(a))
```

Your example string is 6 characters long. Because your solution isn't working (you're not altering the string except to replace the 'A' of 'AB' to 'C') the length of the string will not change. So when you exit the `while` loop, the value of `i` will be `strlen(a)-1`, which cannot possibly also be the same as `strlen(a)`.

The are a lot of ways to do what want. One possible solution is to have a second string to copy the result in to and then copy it back again like this

```
int i,j;
char a[]="helablo";
char *b;
b=malloc(strlen(a)+1);

for(i=0,j=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
  if((a[i]=='a')&&(a[i+1]=='b'))
    {
    b[j++]='c';
    i++;
    }
  else
    {
    b[j++]=a[i];
    }
  }
b[j]='\0';
strcpy(a,b);
free(b);
printf("%s\n",a);
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY not sure what exactly you've spotted, but I did realise I forgot to skip over the matched 'b'

Comment: It still has a mistake.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it's probably not perfect, but it now does what the OP is asking

Comment: `(a[i]!='\0')||(a[i+1]!='\0')` is definitely bad.

Comment: You are going to skip the last character

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I've compiled and tested the code and it definitely doesn't skip the last character

Comment: `(a[i]!='\0')||((a[i])&&(a[i+1]!='\0'))` is the same as `a[i] || (a[i] && a[i+1])`. that doesn't make sense. Should be `a[i] && a[i+1]`

Comment: BTW `||((a[i])&&(a[i+1]!='\0'))` : This has no meaning. So you can delete it. (The meaning does not change even if deleted)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt that skips the last character tho

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ah, yeah - I have been trying to make that bit overly complicated haven't I :/

Comment: You forget to erase one parenthesis(`)`).

Comment: right, you had to append them in the end. I thought the original idea was to break the loop when "ab" can't be found any more. Your updated version is fine

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    int i=0,j=0;
    char a[]="helablo";
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(a[i]=='a'&& a[i+1]=='b'){
            a[i]='c';
            for(j=i+1;j<strlen(a);j++){
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't output anything because
you looped till you find 'a' and 'b' continuosly .

so for i=4 you found a[i]='a' and a[i+1]='b' since its found a[j]='\0' where j=0 initially.so your string "HEABLO" became like this "\0EABLO"

when you perform strlen(a) it returns 0 and i has a value of 4 because you used a continue statement and i value doesn't get incremented it stays at 4 .

now in while loop its checked 4<0 it fails and similarly if conditional statement also fails because if(4==0) so printf doesn't gets executed

simple code to perform your task :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char a[]="helabablo";
   char *p=a;
   while(*(p+1)!='\0')
   {
     if(*p=='a'&&*(p+1)=='b')
     {
       *(p++)='l';
       *(p++)='\0';
       strcat(a,p);
       p-=2;
     }
     p++;
   }
   printf("%s\n",a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Your answer seems quite convincing. But would you like to  rephrase the part "...  since its found  ...", that is a little clunky to read. Minor improvements would be possible with some capital letters at the start of sentences and maybe some formatting for the code parts. Not really necessary with a good explanation, but also probably an improvement, would be a code to demonstrate the described solution. Have fun.